# Definition of a Cartesian Closed Category

Tags: category-theory, definition, cartesian-closed-categories

I would like to check with someone that the following of a **Cartesian Closed Category** is correct and that I did not make a mistake when translating to a notation with predicate quantifiers.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category where $\mathcal{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ and $\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{C})$ denote the category $\mathcal{C}$'s class of objects and its morphisms respectively.

We say that the category $\mathcal{C}$ is a **Cartesian Closed Category** if and only if:

- $\exists T\in \mathcal{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) \ni (\forall O \in \mathcal{Obj}(\mathcal{C}),\; \exists !\;a \in \mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{C}) \ni O \xrightarrow{\;\; a \;\;} T)$
- $\forall A,B \in \mathcal{Obj}(\mathcal{C}),\; \exists (A\times B) \in \mathcal{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) $
- $\forall A,B \in \mathcal{Obj}(\mathcal{C}),\; \exists (A^B) \in \mathcal{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) $

Comment: You've written down a bunch of symbols without indicating what they mean. This is hardly a definition.

Comment: @ZhenLin Sorry but could you elaborate on which part you find confusing? That's not a very constructive comment.

Comment: I suspect that many readers of your question are put off by the use of $\ni$ for "such that". This notation is *extremely* uncommon in mathematics, probably because it's potentially confusing and just looks wrong.

Comment: I think that what Zhen Lin means is that writing "$\exists (A\times B)\in \text{Obj}(C)$" doesn't tell you anything about what the object $A\times B$ is supposed to be. What you mean is "$A$ and $B$ have a product $A\times B$ in $C$", or you could write "$\exists (A\times B)\in \text{Obj}(C)$ such that $A\times B$ is a product of $A$ and $B$". There's no reason to avoid using words when writing mathematics!

Comment: ... And then to give a full definition, one should also given the definition of "product", and similarly for "exponential object". Note that you did this for the terminal object, i.e. you didn't just write $\exists 1\in \text{Obj}(C)$ and leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your question is that it is sort of clear what your intention is, but you use highly unconventional notation - rendering your question nearly nonsensical. To answer your question, I first interpret it as follows: the first condition states that the category has a weakly terminal object. The second condition states that any two objects have a categorical product. The third condition states that any two objects give rise to an exponential, presumably with respect to the mentioned products. So, you are asking if a cartesian closed category is the same as one with a weakly terminal object, in which binary products exist, and all objects are exponentiable. This is not the case. Every cartesian closed category satisfies these three conditions, but not vise versa. You need to change the first condition so that it assures a terminal object exists (i.e., require the uniqueness of the morphism).

Comment: Thank you! I have strengthen the first condition. Could you give an example of what would be a more "conventional notation"?

Comment: you can find the conventional notation in plenty of sources.

Comment: I would not ask you to describe "conventional notation" if I knew what to look for.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category

Comment: @ErwanAaron Well, where are you learning about these things? Cartesian closed categories are often a prelude to studying toposes, for which the easiest introduction is Maclane and Moerdijk's Sheaves in Geometry and Logic. But more context would help to give a better reference. You might also just look at an general book on category theory to see how people actually write things.

Comment: @IttayWeiss My guess is the OP has translated this definition from that in Wikipedia, which doesn't make immediately obvious that one should actually say what products and exponentials *are*.

Comment: @KevinCarlson you don't have to say what they are, but what OP did is not just not say what they are, but used a strange notation. I agree, this is probably just an interpretation of the wiki page stated, for whatever reason, using logical symbols. Obviously, if OP does not know what products and exponentials are, he should find out. That did not seem to be the question though.

Comment: HI, if you need a good reference for study of category theory  write in the actuality maybe this can be do a good reference OXFORD LOGIC GUIDES Series EditorsD.M. GABBAYA.J. MACINTYRE D.S. SCOTT, and obvioslly always is good read categories for the working mathematicias, by mac lane. I hope the best in your lectures.